# Proper vim-latex config on Ubuntu

Tags: latex, vim

I have installed the `vim-latex` package using Ubuntu Synaptic package manager and updated my `.vimrc` file following the [instructions from the documentation](https://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/recommended-settings.html). However, when I open a `.tex` file in Vim, none of the new menu options appear, and I can’t seem to compile documents using `\ll`. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Debian (and, hence, Ubuntu), Vim plugins are installed in two steps:

1. The plugin files are installed from the `.deb` package containing that
   plugin.
2. Symbolic links to those files are created inside `~/.vim/` directories for
   users that would like to use the plugin.

The latter step is supposed to be performed manually by the administrator or
the users themselves via the `vim-addons` script, which allows to examine all
Vim plugins available in the system (that is, installed from packages), and
check their status, both system-wide and for the current user:

```
$ vim-addons status
```

To install a plugin (say, `latex-suite`), run the command

```
$ vim-addons install latex-suite
```

where the last argument stands for the name of the plugin you want to install
(check the output of the previous command to find out the correct name).

If you want to install it system-wide, run the same command as root and add
the `-w` option. It is rarely recommended to install a plugin system-wide,
though.

Similarly, you can remove a plugin from your `~/.vim/` directory using

```
$ vim-addons remove latex-suite
```

Again, `vim-addons` here does not touch the plugin’s files themselves; it only
removes the links pointing to them.